# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $f(\mathbb{Q})\subset\mathbb{N}$, then is $f$ unbounded, constant, or non-constant bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $ f(\mathbb{Q})\subset\mathbb{N}$. What can be said about $f$? Is it (1) unbounded, (2) constant, or (3) non-constant bounded?

I think it should be constant, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Kindly help! Thanks & Regards

Comment: You are right .

Comment: Yes. By continuity, $f(\mathbb{R})=f(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\subseteq\overline{f(\mathbb{Q})}=\mathbb{N}$. Since $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is a non-empty connected subset of $\mathbb{N}$, it is a singleton. Therefore $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f$ must be a constant. Suppose not. Pick $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(q_1) > f(q_2)$. Without loss of generality, assume $q_1 < q_2$. Pick any noninteger $y$ between $f(q_1)$ and $f(q_2)$. Then by intermediate value theorem, there exists $x \in (q_1, q_2)$ such that $f(x) = y$. Any rational number sufficiently close to $x$ should not take integer value, a contradiction.